# How do I read this equation related to Combinations with repetitions in natural language?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Here's an [Article](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/basics-of-combinatorics/) from TopCoder about **Combinatorics**, that starts by introducing some basic concepts such as: Combinations and permutations. That part I understood just fine, but then the article diverts a little to say something about the **Combinations with repetition** formula: [image]

That I don't understand:

> It is useful to know that [image]is also the number of integer solutions to this equation:
>
> [image]

Could you please help me understand this equation, I have problems understanding everything that comes **after** the equals sign. I have no idea how to read this equation.

Please help me, I need to understand it in order to move on.

-Jose

Comment: The combinations of 2 in 2 of {a,b,c} are ab, ac, bc, no more. When repetitions are allowed you have besides the combinations, aa, bb and cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is a bit unusual, but the intent is clear.   The comma is a statement separator, and the parenthetical expression is a quantification, and the overlined pair would then be a way of writing an interval.

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots + x_n = k ,\quad x_i\geq 0\; (i\in \overline {1,n})$$

Read: "The series $x_1+x_2+$ and so on to $x_n$, is equal to $k$, where any term $x_i$ is greater or equal to $0$, for all indices $i$ in the integer interval of $1$ to $n$ (inclusive)."

You might more commonly find this expressed as something like:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = k\quad, \text{ where } \forall i\in\{1..n\} : x_i\geq 0$$

In other words, we're counting the non-negative integer solutions for $n$ terms that equal $k$ when they are summed.

Comment: Fabulous answer! You're absolutely right, I AM much more comfortable with your proposed notation, I hadn't seen the notation from the article before ever. Thank you Mr. Kemp, you've just saved me.